# Creating upto n directories

Tags: java, file-io

I want to build all directories up to 'n' directories. For example, suppose I have something like this:

```
File file = new File( "/var/a/b/c/d/e/f/g" );
```

For n=4, I need a method that builds up to 4 directories i.e. till c, and I was wondering if there was a method in a java io library somewhere that does this already.
Is there any modification of mkdir or mkdirs that can serve this purpose.

Comment: make dirs.... didnt work?

Comment: @ΦXocę웃Пepeúpaツ that will create the whole directory upto g, which I don't want

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will want to use `Path.subpath()` :

```
File myPath = new File( "/var/a/b/c/d/e/f/g" );
Path fourLevels = myPath.toPath().subpath(0, 4);
fourLevels.toFile().mkdirs();                        // will create up to /var/a/b/c
```

Comment: [Ideone link](https://ideone.com/dS8e4j) in which you can't see the actual created file, but where `File.toString()` indicates which file *should* get created

Comment: The directory is not getting created.

Comment: @Nobita Does `new File("/var/a/b/c").mkdirs()` work any better? Otherwise I'm afraid that's out of the scope of your question.

Comment: Anyway check that the user executing your jvm has write permission on the lowest already existing directory, presumably `/var/`

Comment: I'm trying to use File f = new File("C:/a/b/c/d/e/f/g");

Comment: See if your user can create `C:/a` without having an admin password prompt. If it can't, that's the problem your program encounter : it tries to create `C:/a` only to have the OS answer with "no you can't, not with that user". You could "execute as admin" your java program to avoid this problem (if you're launching from command line, start this command-line as admin ; if you're launching from an IDE, start this IDE as admin). Taking the habit to do this would be a terrible security practice though. Maybe you should just use a path that starts somewhere else ;)